# How to: Sort items of a DataGrid by Content, not by Name

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

**How to: Sort items of a DataGrid by Content, not by Name**

I am sorting my items of the `DataGrid` by `Name`, but I want to sort them by using the `Content` property. See the last line:

```
listView_BusinessContacts.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Here is my code, that sets the items using C# (WPF):

```
public void SetListViewItems()
    {
        int i = 0;
        string[] companies = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Companies.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

        string itemName = string.Empty;

        foreach (string company in companies)
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\folder.png", UriKind.Relative));
            image.Stretch = Stretch.None;

            Label label = new Label();
            label.Content = companies[i];

            DockPanel.SetDock(image, Dock.Left);
            DockPanel.SetDock(label, Dock.Right);

            DockPanel dockPanel = new DockPanel();
            dockPanel.Children.Add(image);
            dockPanel.Children.Add(label);

            ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
            listViewItem.Content = dockPanel;

            itemName = label.Content.ToString();
            listViewItem.Name = itemName.Replace(" ", "");

            listViewItem.Selected += delegate
            {
                companyContent = label.Content.ToString();
                SetItemsToDataGrid();
            };
            listView_BusinessContacts.Items.Add(listViewItem);
            i++;
        }
        listView_BusinessContacts.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }
```

My problem is, that sorting by `Content` is not working.

Example output by using `Name`: HelloMyNameIsCompany

Example output by using `Content`: Hello My Name Is Company `// NOT WORKING!`

As you know, the `Name` property does not allow blank fields, so I need to `Replace` them. But I do not want to replace them - I want to use the `Content`, but that does not sort correctly. Do you know, how to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: First one is the txt file, second one is the application and the CORRECT sorting (unfortunately by using `Name` and the `Replace` method).

[image: Bild2]
[image: Bild1]

*Sorry for hiding text, but the information in that file contain business matters.*

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you delete all this (horrible) code and use proper XAML and DataBinding. Creating and manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF is not recommended nor needed in any circumnstance.

Comment: As you may see, I need to fill it that way, because I fill it during runtime. How would you fill a `DataGrid` by reading from txt files?

Comment: please post a screenshot of what you need and an example of what the `txt` file looks like and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: Done, see above. Thanks so far!

Comment: @Exception I would recommend parsing the file into an `ObservableCollection<SomeClass>` where `SomeClass` contained properties for your `ImageSource`, `Name`, and `Content`, and then use data binding to bind your `ListView.ItemsSource` to that collection. It's cleaner and much easier to maintain :)

Comment: @Rachel once again, I'm going to answer this by linking to your "WPF mentality" answer. There should be a more automatic way of doing this...